# Embedding Youtube video http / https matching error

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I am embedding a Youtube video on my website like so:

```
<iframe class="frame-for-top" width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nb9GMm7QtlM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now when I open up my console I get an error message for all of my embedded youtube videos that says:

> :1 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://mywebsite.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of
>   "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols
>   must match.

I tried changing the "src" in the iframe to **http** instead of **https** seems to work but I don't know if that's ok to do. Any feedback?

**UPDATE:**

still getting the errors even in the JS fiddle;
[image]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error message using your iframe link: http://jsfiddle.net/poppin3000/m12j3wub/ . Can you share the surrounding code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an [origin parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to your src url and then you can use `http` protocol in your iframe:

> As an extra security measure, you should also include the origin parameter to the URL, specifying the URL scheme (http:// or https://) and full domain of your host page as the parameter value. While origin is optional, including it protects against malicious third-party JavaScript being injected into your page and hijacking control of your YouTube player.

Example:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb9GMm7QtlM?origin=http://mywebsite.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Even seven years ago when this answer was suggested and accepted it wasn't really quite correct. Let me put this gently:  un-encrypted transport is the work of Satan and answers which suggest "fixing" problems by making http "work" should be banned and scrubbed from Stack Overflow. Make https work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoID"
```

It worked for me.